# How to split pyspark dataframe and create new columns

Tags: python, dataframe, hive, pyspark

I have sample input dataframe as below, but the value (clm starting with m) columns can be n number. Also I used customer_id as a primary key (but, I can have more no# of primary key based on the input data).

```
customer_id|month_id|m1    |m2 |m3 ....to....m_n
1001      |  01    |10     |20    
1002      |  01    |20     |30    
1003      |  01    |30     |40
1001      |  02    |40     |50    
1002      |  02    |50     |60    
1003      |  02    |60     |70
1001      |  03    |70     |80    
1002      |  03    |80     |90    
1003      |  03    |90     |100
```

Now, based on the input value columns - I have to calculate the new columns based on the cumulative sum or average. Let's consider an example:

```
cumulative sum on [m1, ......, m10] and 
cumulative avg on [m11, ......., m20] columns
```

Based on this I have to calculate new columns. I have tried it based on the windows function and able to calculate the new columns. But, my problem is because of size of data, I'm doing the calculation one after other with the updated dataframe with new columns.

My try:

```
a = [m1, ......, m10]
b = [m11, ......, m20]
rnum = (Window.partitionBy("partner_id").orderBy("month_id").rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))
for item in a:
   var = n
   df = df.withColumn(var + item[1:], F.sum(item).over(rnum))
for item in b:
   var = n
   df = df.withColumn(var + item[1:], F.avg(item).over(rnum))
```

**Output data:**

```
customer_id|month_id|m1     |m2    |m11     |m12   |n1   |n2  |n11  |n12
1001       |  01    |10     |20    |10      |20    |10   |20  |10   |20
1002       |  01    |20     |30    |10      |20    |20   |30  |10   |20
1003       |  01    |30     |40    |10      |20    |30   |40  |10   |20
1001       |  02    |40     |50    |10      |20    |50   |35  |10   |20
1002       |  02    |50     |60    |10      |20    |70   |55  |10   |20
1003       |  02    |60     |70    |10      |20    |90   |75  |10   |20
1001       |  03    |70     |80    |10      |20    |120  |75  |10   |20
1002       |  03    |80     |90    |10      |20    |150  |105 |10   |20
1003       |  03    |90     |100   |10      |20    |180  |135 |10   |20
```

But, can we do the same operation by splitting the dataframe into two, with cumulative sum columns in one and cumulative avg columns in another data frame along with primary key and then do the operation then club the calculated dataframe????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DF1 Approach Optimized Logical Plan**

```
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
GlobalLimit 21
+- LocalLimit 21
   +- Project [m1#15, m2#16, sum1#27, sum2#38, customer_id#5334, month_id#5335, m3#5338, m4#5339, avg3#465, avg4#474]
      +- Join Inner, ((customer_id#13 = customer_id#5334) && (month_id#14 = month_id#5335))
         :- Project [customer_id#13, month_id#14, m1#15, m2#16, sum1#27, sum2#38]
         :  +- Filter isnotnull(month_id#14)
         :     +- Window [sum(_w0#39) windowspecdefinition(customer_id#13, month_id#14 ASC NULLS FIRST, RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS sum2#38], [customer_id#13], [month_id#14 ASC NULLS FIRST]
         :        +- Project [customer_id#13, month_id#14, m1#15, m2#16, sum1#27, cast(m2#16 as double) AS _w0#39]
         :           +- Window [sum(_w0#28) windowspecdefinition(customer_id#13, month_id#14 ASC NULLS FIRST, RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS sum1#27], [customer_id#13], [month_id#14 ASC NULLS FIRST]
         :              +- Project [customer_id#13, month_id#14, m1#15, m2#16, cast(m1#15 as double) AS _w0#28]
         :                 +- Filter isnotnull(customer_id#13)
         :                    +- LogicalRDD [customer_id#13, month_id#14, m1#15, m2#16, m3#17, m4#18]
         +- Project [customer_id#5334, month_id#5335, m3#5338, m4#5339, avg3#465, avg4#474]
            +- Filter isnotnull(month_id#5335)
               +- Window [avg(_w0#475) windowspecdefinition(customer_id#5334, month_id#5335 ASC NULLS FIRST, RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS avg4#474], [customer_id#5334], [month_id#5335 ASC NULLS FIRST]
                  +- Project [customer_id#5334, month_id#5335, m3#5338, m4#5339, avg3#465, cast(m4#5339 as double) AS _w0#475]
                     +- Window [avg(_w0#466) windowspecdefinition(customer_id#5334, month_id#5335 ASC NULLS FIRST, RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS avg3#465], [customer_id#5334], [month_id#5335 ASC NULLS FIRST]
                        +- Project [customer_id#5334, month_id#5335, m3#5338, m4#5339, cast(m3#5338 as double) AS _w0#466]
                           +- Filter isnotnull(customer_id#5334)
                              +- LogicalRDD [customer_id#5334, month_id#5335, m1#5336, m2#5337, m3#5338, m4#5339]
```

**DF Approach Optimized Logical Plan**

```
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
GlobalLimit 21
+- LocalLimit 21
   +- Project [customer_id#0, month_id#1, m1#2, m2#3, m3#4, m4#5, sum1#14, sum2#25, avg3#447, avg4#460]
      +- Window [avg(_w0#461) windowspecdefinition(customer_id#0, month_id#1 ASC NULLS FIRST, RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS avg4#460], [customer_id#0], [month_id#1 ASC NULLS FIRST]
         +- Project [customer_id#0, month_id#1, m1#2, m2#3, m3#4, m4#5, sum1#14, sum2#25, avg3#447, cast(m4#5 as double) AS _w0#461]
            +- Window [avg(_w0#448) windowspecdefinition(customer_id#0, month_id#1 ASC NULLS FIRST, RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS avg3#447], [customer_id#0], [month_id#1 ASC NULLS FIRST]
               +- Project [customer_id#0, month_id#1, m1#2, m2#3, m3#4, m4#5, sum1#14, sum2#25, cast(m3#4 as double) AS _w0#448]
                  +- Window [sum(_w0#26) windowspecdefinition(customer_id#0, month_id#1 ASC NULLS FIRST, RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS sum2#25], [customer_id#0], [month_id#1 ASC NULLS FIRST]
                     +- Project [customer_id#0, month_id#1, m1#2, m2#3, m3#4, m4#5, sum1#14, cast(m2#3 as double) AS _w0#26]
                        +- Window [sum(_w0#15) windowspecdefinition(customer_id#0, month_id#1 ASC NULLS FIRST, RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS sum1#14], [customer_id#0], [month_id#1 ASC NULLS FIRST]
                           +- Project [customer_id#0, month_id#1, m1#2, m2#3, m3#4, m4#5, cast(m1#2 as double) AS _w0#15]
                              +- LogicalRDD [customer_id#0, month_id#1, m1#2, m2#3, m3#4, m4#5]
```

If you see the above `DF Approach Optimized Logical Plan`, It has SUM calculation plan during AVG calculation which might be inefficient.

```
+- Window [sum(_w0#26) windowspecdefinition(customer_id#0, month_id#1 ASC NULLS FIRST, RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS sum2#25], [customer_id#0], [month_id#1 ASC NULLS FIRST]
                     +- Project [customer_id#0, month_id#1, m1#2, m2#3, m3#4, m4#5, sum1#14, cast(m2#3 as double) AS _w0#26]
                        +- Window [sum(_w0#15) windowspecdefinition(customer_id#0, month_id#1 ASC NULLS FIRST, RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS sum1#14],
```

You can narrow down the dataframe size whenever it is possible and proceed with the calculations. At the same time `join` plan got added for two datasets in the DF1 Optimized Logical Plan. In many cases joins are always slow, so better try to perfomance tune your spark engine execution environment by,

- `code - repartition & cache`
- `configs - executor, driver, memoryOverhead, number of cores`

code I have tried with `m1,m2,m3,m4` columns.

```
# pyspark --driver-memory 1G --executor-memory 2G --executor-cores 1 --num-executors 1
from pyspark.sql import Row
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

drow = Row("customer_id","month_id","m1","m2","m3","m4")

data=[drow("1001","01","10","20","10","20"),drow("1002","01","20","30","20","30"),drow("1003","01","30","40","30","40"),drow("1001","02","40","50","40","50"),drow("1002","02","50","60","50","60"),drow("1003","02","60","70","60","70"),drow("1001","03","70","80","70","80"),drow("1002","03","80","90","80","90"),drow("1003","03","90","100","90","100")]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

df1=df.select("customer_id","month_id","m3","m4")

a = ["m1","m2"]
b = ["m3","m4"]
rnum = (Window.partitionBy("customer_id").orderBy("month_id").rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))
for item in a:
    var = "sum"
    df = df.withColumn(var + item[1:], F.sum(item).over(rnum))
df.show()
'''
+-----------+--------+---+---+---+---+-----+-----+
|customer_id|month_id| m1| m2| m3| m4| sum1| sum2|
+-----------+--------+---+---+---+---+-----+-----+
|       1003|      01| 30| 40| 30| 40| 30.0| 40.0|
|       1003|      02| 60| 70| 60| 70| 90.0|110.0|
|       1003|      03| 90|100| 90|100|180.0|210.0|
|       1002|      01| 20| 30| 20| 30| 20.0| 30.0|
|       1002|      02| 50| 60| 50| 60| 70.0| 90.0|
|       1002|      03| 80| 90| 80| 90|150.0|180.0|
|       1001|      01| 10| 20| 10| 20| 10.0| 20.0|
|       1001|      02| 40| 50| 40| 50| 50.0| 70.0|
|       1001|      03| 70| 80| 70| 80|120.0|150.0|
+-----------+--------+---+---+---+---+-----+-----+
'''
for item in b:
    var = "avg"
    df = df.withColumn(var + item[1:], F.avg(item).over(rnum))
df.show()

'''
+-----------+--------+---+---+---+---+-----+-----+----+----+
|customer_id|month_id| m1| m2| m3| m4| sum1| sum2|avg3|avg4|
+-----------+--------+---+---+---+---+-----+-----+----+----+
|       1003|      01| 30| 40| 30| 40| 30.0| 40.0|30.0|40.0|
|       1003|      02| 60| 70| 60| 70| 90.0|110.0|45.0|55.0|
|       1003|      03| 90|100| 90|100|180.0|210.0|60.0|70.0|
|       1002|      01| 20| 30| 20| 30| 20.0| 30.0|20.0|30.0|
|       1002|      02| 50| 60| 50| 60| 70.0| 90.0|35.0|45.0|
|       1002|      03| 80| 90| 80| 90|150.0|180.0|50.0|60.0|
|       1001|      01| 10| 20| 10| 20| 10.0| 20.0|10.0|20.0|
|       1001|      02| 40| 50| 40| 50| 50.0| 70.0|25.0|35.0|
|       1001|      03| 70| 80| 70| 80|120.0|150.0|40.0|50.0|
+-----------+--------+---+---+---+---+-----+-----+----+----+
'''

for item in b:
    var = "avg"
    df1 = df1.withColumn(var + item[1:], F.avg(item).over(rnum))

'''
+-----------+--------+---+---+----+----+
|customer_id|month_id| m3| m4|avg3|avg4|
+-----------+--------+---+---+----+----+
|       1003|      01| 30| 40|30.0|40.0|
|       1003|      02| 60| 70|45.0|55.0|
|       1003|      03| 90|100|60.0|70.0|
|       1002|      01| 20| 30|20.0|30.0|
|       1002|      02| 50| 60|35.0|45.0|
|       1002|      03| 80| 90|50.0|60.0|
|       1001|      01| 10| 20|10.0|20.0|
|       1001|      02| 40| 50|25.0|35.0|
|       1001|      03| 70| 80|40.0|50.0|
+-----------+--------+---+---+----+----+
'''
#join the DFs after DF1 avg & DF sum calculation.

df2=df.join(df1,(df1.customer_id == df.customer_id)& (df1.month_id == df.month_id)).drop(df.m3).drop(df.m4).drop(df1.month_id).drop(df1.customer_id)

'''
df2.show()
+---+---+-----+-----+-----------+--------+---+---+----+----+
| m1| m2| sum1| sum2|customer_id|month_id| m3| m4|avg3|avg4|
+---+---+-----+-----+-----------+--------+---+---+----+----+
| 10| 20| 10.0| 20.0|       1001|      01| 10| 20|10.0|20.0|
| 70| 80|120.0|150.0|       1001|      03| 70| 80|40.0|50.0|
| 40| 50| 50.0| 70.0|       1001|      02| 40| 50|25.0|35.0|
| 80| 90|150.0|180.0|       1002|      03| 80| 90|50.0|60.0|
| 50| 60| 70.0| 90.0|       1002|      02| 50| 60|35.0|45.0|
| 20| 30| 20.0| 30.0|       1002|      01| 20| 30|20.0|30.0|
| 30| 40| 30.0| 40.0|       1003|      01| 30| 40|30.0|40.0|
| 90|100|180.0|210.0|       1003|      03| 90|100|60.0|70.0|
| 60| 70| 90.0|110.0|       1003|      02| 60| 70|45.0|55.0|
+---+---+-----+-----+-----------+--------+---+---+----+----+
'''
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a point. Can we prepare an expression for calculating all new columns and then pass the expr to the selectExpr() to calculate all new columns at a time???

Comment: FYI - Crt one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63265792/how-to-select-columns-using-dynamic-select-query-using-window-function

Comment: let me look into it later today.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, my understanding is that you are trying to split the operation to perform the tasks in parallel and to save time.

You don't have to parallelize the execution since the execution will be automatically parallelized in spark when you perform any operations such as collect(), show(), count(), write on the dataframe you have created. This is due to spark's lazy execution

If you still want to split the operations for some other reason, you can use threading. Below article will give you more information about threading in pyspark : https://medium.com/@everisUS/threads-in-pyspark-a6e8005f6017